# what's the crash resson NSfileHandle.fd_monitoring?

Tags: objective-c

I have encountered some problems： Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSFileHandle.fd_monitoring

```
Thread 15 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSFileHandle.fd_monitoring
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ddf32c6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7deaebf1 pthread_kill + 284
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff7dd5d6a6 abort + 127
3   net.hockeyapp.sdk.mac           0x000000010b3ba1bc uncaught_exception_handler + 59
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff51e912e9 __handleUncaughtException + 775
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff7c4ecedd _objc_terminate() + 91
6   net.hockeyapp.sdk.mac           0x000000010b39c3ea BITCrashUncaughtCXXTerminateHandler() + 4074
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff7af4519e std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff7af45213 std::terminate() + 51
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7dc6b651 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7dc6dde6 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7dc7cf42 _dispatch_source_invoke + 2056
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7dc71792 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 268
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7dc72396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7dc7a6ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7deab611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7deab3fd start_wqthread + 13
```